# Appending a vertex delaration

Tags: c++, directx, declaration, vertex

I have been converting the uvatlas project in the 2010 sdk to a windows application from a console app. It is falling over on the append vertex declaration function, so I have attempted to create a function that appends a vertex declaration to an array of vertex declarations (returned by the mesh) but it looks like my code is only returning a single element.

```
D3DVERTEXELEMENT9* appenddecl( D3DVERTEXELEMENT9 decl_add,
                           D3DVERTEXELEMENT9* source, 
                           D3DVERTEXELEMENT9* decl_out,
                           UINT num_decl )
```

{

```
WORD i = 0;
UINT last_offset = 0;
BYTE last_type = 0;
UINT n_offset = 0;


for( i = 0; i < num_decl; i++ )
{
    decl_out->Method = source->Method;
    decl_out->Offset = source->Offset;
    decl_out->Stream = source->Stream;
    decl_out->Type = source->Type;
    decl_out->Usage = source->Usage;
    decl_out->UsageIndex = source->UsageIndex;

    last_offset = decl_out->Offset;
    last_type = decl_out->Type;

    *decl_out++;
    *source++;


}


switch(last_type)
{

    case 0:
     n_offset   = 4;
     break;

     case 1:
      n_offset     = 8;
      break;

     case 2:
      n_offset    = 12;
      break;

      case 3:
      n_offset     = 16;
     break;

    case 4:
     n_offset   = 4;
     break;

  default:

      break;

}


    decl_out->Method = decl_add.Method;             
    decl_out->Offset =  last_offset + n_offset; 
    decl_out->Stream = 0;
    decl_out->Type = decl_add.Type;
    decl_out->Usage = decl_add.Usage;
    decl_out->UsageIndex = 1;
```

return decl_out;

}`

Any Ideas ?

Thanks . . .`

Comment: Curiously, the append function is now working . . . I am knakered !

Comment: There's an updated version of the UVAtlas command-line tool and the UVAtlas library that does not make use of the legacy DirectX SDK or D3DX9. It is hosted on [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/UVAtlas). See [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2014/11/14/uvatlas-return-of-the-isochart.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for that, I have given it a good few hours today and have made a lot of progress, I am still working with DirectX 9 jun2010 as I like to finish what I start . . . like being able to create a pure c++ directx 9 mini editor for instance . . . also kind of busy with Blender and Unity, so I guess you could say I was on my way to DirectX 12, the scenic route though . . .

Comment: Not much value in investing in Direct3D 9 these days... Direct3D 11 is a great option for basically everyone, with the experts who need the extra perf going to DirectX 12.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the first pass, hey success !

[opened into app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olPZ9.jpg)